# Cannot start android sdk manager using eclipse luna

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to use Eclipse Luna with android SDK tool on Windows 7 professional. The java version is 1.8 (32 bit). I have installed android plugins and have done the necessary installation which includes Android SDK in `c:\Android\androidsdk\`. I updated the android.bat file to have proper java path links. Initially I was getting swt path errors which I fixed. When I run SDK manager as standalone or from eclipse, I am getting the following error:

```
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:402)
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:376)
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[2015-01-30 11:25:11 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   ... 4 more
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Android SDK used is android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows

Comment: this are changes to my android.bat - set java_exe="C:\Java32\jdk\bin\java.exe"; also this change  - call "%java_exe% %REMOTE_DEBUG%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir=%tools_dir%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir=%work_dir%" -classpath "%tools_dir%\%jar_path%;%tools_dir%\%swt_path%\swt.jar" com.android.sdkmanager.Main %*

Answer (score 0):

Check If JDK and JRE are installed properly and the path is set in Environment Variables. Open command prompt and type "java". If command prompt is not accepting java command then you should configure properly.
I had the same problem and I solved it by reinstalling JDK and by setting path in Environment Variables.

Comment: c:\Android\androidsdk\tools>java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode, sharing)

c:\Android\androidsdk\tools>

Comment: Find out java path in programfiles and copy that path and open system settings>advance>Environment Variables and open path variable and paste that copied java path and save. This will definately solve your problem.

Comment: I still get the same error if I run as administrator. I have installed my java jdk kit in c:\java32 and my PATH and JAVA_HOME are pointing to c:\java32\jdk\bin. I have also set ANDRIOD_SWT to point to c:Android\androidsdk\tools\lib\x86 which has swt.jar file

Comment: Then just give a try to point the java_home variable to jre\bin .

Comment: even after setting to jre\bin, I get the same error